# Importing type in test file gave `undefined` variable

Tags: go

I wrote the below simple code, in order to try `test` in go:

```golang
package main

// Init is the input number, to be used as struct insted of directly calling
// the functions for simplicity purposes
type Init struct {
    Number int
}

func main() {
    d := Init{Number: 3}
    d.Double()
    println(d.Number, "(which is 3 by 2)")
}

// Double function retuning the input value multiplied by 2
func (d *Init) Double() {
    d.Number = d.Number * 2
}

func ExampleDouble() {
    // Create new buffer for the image
    d := Init{Number: 3}
    d.Double()
    println(d.Number, "(which is 3 by 2)")
    // Output:
    // 6 (which is 3 by 2)
}
```

And the `double_test.go` file is:

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func TestDouble(t *testing.T) {
    d := Init{Number: 3}
    d.Double()
    want := 6
    if got := d.Number; got != want {
        println("test failed")
    } else {
        println("test passed")
    }
}
```

While running:

```sh
go test -v double_test.go
```

I got the below error:

```sh
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
.\double_test.go:6:7: undefined: Init
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
FAIL
```

What is wrong here, should not the test file read the `Init` type as it is capitalized?

Comment: By specifying a file you're telling `go test` to only build that file, i.e. the other files in that package won't be included in the test build. Try `go test -v`.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks alot, it is done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mkopriva noted, *by specifying a test file you're telling Go to only build that file, i.e. the other files in that package won't be included in the test build.*

Either run all tests with `go test -v` or specify the source files that your test depends on, e.g.

```
go test double.go double_test.go
```

if your first file was named `double.go`.

Answer (score -1):

Building on the comment, by specifying a file you're telling go test to only build that file, i.e. the other files in that package won't be included in the test build. so, the solution is to use:

```sh
go test -v
```